# Sum over non-negative elements of a list

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100}{L_i}$. Some of the $L_i$ are negative. How can I write a *Mathematica* expression so as to omit those $L_i$ which are negative? Something like $\sum{L_i\, {\rm sign} (L_i)}$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the software [Mathematica](http://wri.com/).

Comment: `Total@Cases[lis, x_ /; x > 0]`  or  `Total@Select[lis, Positive]`

Comment: $L_i \cdot {\rm sign} (L_i)$ will be just $|L_i|$ - not changing negative $L_i$ to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[0]
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10]
```

> {0.304936, 0.266141, 0.365626, 0.132704, 0.870404, 0.952376,
>   -0.523097, 0.275125, -0.797803, 0.291049}

An explicit sum would be

```
Sum[ If[list[[i]] > 0, list[[i]], 0], {i, Length@list}]
 (* or *)
Sum[ list[[i]]*Boole[list[[i]] > 0], {i, Length@list}]
```

By pre-selecting positive entries

```
Select[list, # > 0 &] // Total
 (* or *)
Select[list, Positive] // Total
```

Or more functional

```
# UnitStep[#] & /@ list // Total
 (* or *)
Clip[list, {0, Infinity}] // Total
```

All give

> 3.45836

---

In v11 there's [`Ramp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html):

```
Ramp[list] // Total
```

Comment: Also `Total@Clip[list, {0, Infinity}]`. But I don't think he was asking about Mathematica.

Comment: One more: `Total[Ramp[list]]`.

Comment: I didn't know about the new `Ramp` func - cool